# Retrieving image file from GridFS using Django, MongoEngine

Tags: django, mongoengine, gridfs

I have stored an image file in GridFS and want to retrieve it and display it in my Django Template.
I have created a view which returns an HTTP response as per the following question:
[Retrieving images from GridFS using django-tastypie-mongoengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323384/retrieving-images-from-gridfs-using-django-tastypie-mongoengine)
The http-response contains the binary-data and the content type
How can I use this response to display the image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit the img data from GridFS to html via base64.

In your django views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
def home(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'home.html', 
        { 'img_b64': img.read().encode("base64"),}
    )
```

In your django template home.html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{img_b64}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

To serve files out of GridFS, use tools like [nginx-gridfs](https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs). Never serve files through Django in production!